# MVC - What is the meaning of RouteContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to understand the Following statement

> If the UrlRoutingModule successfully retrieves a RouteData object then
>   the module next creates a RouteContext object that represents the
>   current HttpContext and RouteData. The module then instantiates a new
>   HttpHandler based on the RouteTable and passes the RouteContext to the
>   new handler’s constructor.

**[I studied it from here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx)**

Query - What is the meaning of RouteContext? I searched a lot on Google. But could not found any reference

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://www.codethinked.com/exploring-systemwebrouting

Answer (score 1):

What I understood that `RouteContext` is composed of `HttpContext` and `RouteData`.
I will remove this answer whenever I found some other useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not finding anything is because it's called `RequestContext`, not *RouteContext*.

Comment: Sorry for the -1, but it's been around for a while https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.requestcontext(v=vs.90).aspx albeit very hard to find!

Comment: I think I understood it ok, you're saying that RouteContext doesn't exist and instead thought the question was regarding RequestContext. But RouteContext does exist and looks like it is what the OP is referring to? Unless I've misunderstood your answer?

Comment: Sorry @Max an MSDN search failure on my part. I hopped between ASP.net 5 (where it does exist now) and thought I grabbed the .net 3 - 4.5 URL (more applicable when the question was asked) but obviously completely pasted the wrong thing. My bad! -1 becomes +1 happy days.

Answer (score 0):

RouteContext is special object that contains HttpContext object and some other data. It is wrapper above HttpContext. It hide HttpContext, but reveal some of its properties in useful form.

Comment: Will you like you share a link ?

Comment: What link do you want? I interpret statement that you want to uderstand. My interpretation is based on my own knowledge how asp.net mvc works and using of different contexts in it (ControllerContext, FilterContext and so on).

Comment: **It hide HttpContext, but reveal some of its properties in useful form.** - Which useful properties will be revealed in useful form ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to understand but I will have a go here. So the definition of context is The circumstances in which an event occurs; a setting. A context helps us to understand something.

In ASP.Net MVC a route is how we map the URL to controller and an action. I understand the RouteContext to be all the information and surrounding data that helped us pick and determine a route. Obviously the HttpContext is something that helped determine the route.

Comment: A Route object is responsible for mapping URLs to handlers. If match found returns RouteData.

Comment: @ihihjkjk I get that. I was trying to explain RouteContext. I thought maybe you had a problem conceptualizing it from the name. The route context will contain the route data from what you pasted here.